# Stored procedure returns NULL despite declaring OUTPUT parameter when executing

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure. But when I execute it, the 'null' value is always returned although I declared '@total' as output parameter.

This is my stored procedure:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[GetTotalInsectsInTrap]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTotalInsectsInTrap]

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTotalInsectsInTrap] 
    @Date DATE, @Kind NVARCHAR, @TotalQuantity INT OUTPUT AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @TotalQuantity = SUM(CTD.Quantity)
    FROM 
        CheckTrapDetails AS CTD
    JOIN 
        CheckTraps AS CT 
        ON CT.Id = CTD.CheckTrapId
    JOIN 
        Insects AS I 
        ON I.Id = CTD.InsectId
    WHERE 
        CT.Date = @Date AND 
        I.Kind = @Kind
    GROUP BY 
        I.Kind, 
        CT.Date
END
```

This is the executing code generated by SSMS:

```
USE [OP_Insect]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @TotalQuantity int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetTotalInsectsInTrap]
        @Date = '2021-05-04',
        @Kind = N'Rầy nâu',
        @TotalQuantity = @TotalQuantity OUTPUT

SELECT  @TotalQuantity as N'@TotalQuantity'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

This is the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Dft.png)

I am using SQL Server 2017 and SSMS 18. I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Check out the "new" [`DROP IF EXISTS`](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/ba-p/384562) and/or [`CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4640/new-create-or-alter-statement-in-sql-server-2016-sp1/) statements that make life a lot easier in SQL Server!

Comment: What results do you see when you run the query outside the proc with the same parameter values without the variable assignment? Perhaps `SUM(CTD.Quantity)` is NULL.

Comment: @DanGuzman the query returns the exact result. But when I run the procedure it returns null.

Comment: @marc_s thanks. it's been awhile since the latest time I use SQL Server.

Comment: By the way, you should not use `''` to delimit column names. Delimit them with `[]` *where necessary* here you don't need to at all

Comment: @Charlieface You probably mean the '@TotalQuantity' and 'Return Value' columns in the procedure executing query. That's just automatically generated by the SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify length of nvarchar field for @Kind in the following e.g., nvarchar(50). .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTotalInsectsInTrap] 
    @Date DATE, @Kind NVARCHAR, @TotalQuantity INT OUTPUT AS
```

nvarchar without a number usually defaults to nvarchar(1) - which I'm assuming your insects are not called by

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the solution for my problem.